# Как пропустить если нет ответа от устройства

Tags: php

PHP Warning:  snmprealwalk(): No response from IP

Есть цикл перебора ip адресов *.*.*.1-254, но не все IP заняты, как сделать чтобы цикл не вис при ожидании ответа .

```
 for($i=1;$i<=254;$i++)
{
$dats=snmprealwalk("192.168.0.".$i."", "public", "");
if($dats==true)
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У метода snmprealwalk есть параметр ожидание ответа сервера вот его нужно использовать `$dats=snmprealwalk("192.168.0.".$i."", "public", "", 10, 1);`
 про это написано в документации [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmprealwalk.php)